# How to return char *arr[] with variable length in C?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

I want to refactor a function so that I can use it for arrays of different lengths and return that newly created array so that other functions can access it. I can't make the array static since you can't have static arrays with dynamic length. I also can't use a global struct because that needs to take the length of the array and that has to be hardcoded I think.
So the question is whether it is even possible to do something like this:

```
char* splitElementsArr(FILE* file){
    int length = countBlankLines(file);
    char *arr[length] // or maybe use malloc here

    ...Some operations to fill array

    return arr;
```

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be an array of pointers, not an array of `char`?

Comment: But the difference has little impact on the answer.

Comment: @Barmar Yes its an array of strings

Comment: @Barmar The function is assumed to split the file into chunks, so I'm not suprised it returns an array of pointers.

Comment: @xhienne Good point. It was the fact that the array is sized based on the file length that confused me. But I guess that's just an upper bound.

Comment: @Barmar Right, the function `countFileLength` is probably ill-named.

Comment: @Barmar yes I accidentally used the wrong function ... may bad

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You are returning a pointer to local data that were dynamically allocated on the stack. As soon as you return, those data no longer exist.

Solution : use `malloc()`.

Comment: And then just call free() at the end of whole program?

Comment: Whenever you don't need those data any longer, you call `free()`. One `free()` for each `malloc()`.

Comment: You'll also need to free all the `arr[i]`. @Phil

Comment: @Phil And do all `free(arr[i])` before `free(arr)` :-)